# Can't add parameter 'this'

Tags: java, android, sqlite

It works in MainAcitvity.class, but doesn't work in QueryUtils.class.

```
private WeatherDBHelper weatherDBHelper = new WeatherDBHelper(this);
```

[image]

Comment: Include all of that as text, not an image. Images are useless to us.

Comment: Please include the full compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure `WeatherDBHelper` constructor receieve Context as param

```
Public class WeatherDBHelper{
     Context context;
     public WeatherDBHelper(Context context){
         this.context = context;
     }
     ....
}
```

#### EDIT

The `WeatherDBHelper` only receive Context as param. QueryUtils dont have the Context type.

it can be done where add context in QueryUtils class

```
Context context;
private WeatherDBHelper weatherDBHelper;
public QueryUtils(Context context){
     this.context = context;
     weatherDBHelper = new WeatherDBHelper(context); 
}
```

use in MainActivity

```
QueryUtils qt = new QueryUtils(this);
```

Comment: there no problem with `WeatherDBHelper`, cuz `private WeatherDBHelper weatherDBHelper = new WeatherDBHelper(this); ` work in `MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Your class QueryUtilis should
extend SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `WeatherDBHelper` needs a `Context` object and `QueryUtils` isn't of type `Context`, so `this` won't work here.

The reason you can use `this` successfully in `MainActivity` is that `MainActivity` is an `Activity`, which is a child class of `Context`. Here's its object hierarchy:

```
java.lang.Object 
↳
    android.content.Context 
    ↳
        android.content.ContextWrapper 
        ↳
            android.view.ContextThemeWrapper 
            ↳
                android.app.Activity
```

So, in `MainActivity`, `this` refers to an object that's actually a `Context`. In `QueryUtils` it doesn't.

You actually need to pass a `Context` to this.